# Pandas drop duplicates across columns

Tags: python, pandas

Good day,

I need a way to check each row of a dataframe and drop the row if all the values in that row (across the `score` columns) are the same. The `person_id` may differ.

Here is a part of the dataset:

**In:**

```
data = [[7, 10, 10, 10, 10], [17, 10, 10, 10, 10], [18, 8, 10, 10, 10], [20, 10, 10, 9, 9], [25, 9, 8, 8, 7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['person_id', 'score_1', 'score_2', 'score_3', 'score_4'])
df
```

**Out:**

```
    person_id   score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4
0   7           10      10      10      10
1   17          10      10      10      10
2   18          8       10      10      10
3   20          10      10      9       9
4   25          9       8       8       7
```

**The desired output would be:**

```
    person_id   score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4
2   18          8       10      10      10
3   20          10      10      9       9
4   25          9       8       8       7
```

Since row 0 (`person_id` 7) and row 1 (`person_id` 17) have the same scores.
The number of columns will also change, adding more `score` columns - thus, I cannot use

```
df_no_duplicates = df.loc[(df.score_1 != df.score_2) | (df.score_2 != df.score_3)| (df.score_3 != df.score_4)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheeky way to omit the person_id column from the process is to set it as the index temporarily.

```
result = df.set_index('person_id').drop_duplicates(keep=False).reset_index()
```

You could also use the `subset` argument of `drop_duplicates`:

```
result = df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns.difference(['person_id']), keep=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `nunique`

```
out = df[df.filter(like='score').nunique(1)>1].copy()
Out[208]: 
   person_id  score_1  score_2  score_3  score_4
2         18        8       10       10       10
3         20       10       10        9        9
4         25        9        8        8        7
```